# Unable to load .mp3 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, pubspec

I want to add music to my project, and I added an .mp3 file, but it says it can't find the assets file.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Music Player',
      home: MusicPlayer(),
    );
  }
}

class MusicPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  \_MusicPlayerState createState() =\>  \_MusicPlayerState();
}

class \_MusicPlayerState extends State \<MusicPlayer\> {
  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
  String musicPath = "assets/audios/Meditation.mp3";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player.load(musicPath);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Music Player'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Play Music'),
          onPressed: () {
            player.loadAsFile(musicPath);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried everything... and still get the same error. How can I fix this?

---

This is the error:

[image]

---

This is pubspec.yaml file:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Also "I tried everything" doesn't tell us much and is plain untrue (you presumably didn't try smearing peanut butter on your screen). Instead, write what you *actually* tried and why that did not produce the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) if you don't set the assets location in pubspec.yaml.

```
    flutter: 
      assets: 
        - audio/
```

This tells Flutter that you have an audio folder in the root of your project where you keep your audio assets.

After doing that, you should be able to set the asset and play it like so:

```
await player.setAsset('audio/cow.mp3'); 
player.play();
```

The error can also happen if you spelled something in the path wrong, but I assume you already checked for that.